# How can I refresh jwt and request the original request again and get the response?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

How can I handle 'refresh token' when 'access_token' is expired?

I know how it works. But what I want to know is implementing once and apply it to all the APIs.

When access token is expired, all the APIs are blocked(401) and need to request new token with refresh token.

So, I tried to do it within 'intercepter' because it can handle the request and response before sending or before handling in the application.

The process is like this.

1. request an API
2. catch the response
3. if it's 401, call refresh token API
4. get the response and request the original API that I was going to call.
5. get the proper response from the original API.

```
// intercepter

val originalRequest = it.request()

val newRequestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()

val response = it.proceed(newRequestBuilder.build())

if (response.code == 401) {

    // TODO: refresh token and request again and get the original response

}

response
```

Answer (score 1):

**Refresh tokens without getting "Error" response from API (Write only once)**

I would suggest you to use `Authenticator`. OkHttp will automatically ask the `Authenticator` for credentials when a response is 401 Not Authorized retrying last failed request with them.

1. Create a class `MyAuthenticator` and add the following code:

   ```
   class MyAuthenticator: Authenticator {


    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

        // set maixmum retry count
        if (response.responseCount >= 3) {
            return null // If we've failed 3 times, give up.
        }


       // write code to refresh the token
        val call = MyRetrofitClient.MyApi().refreshAccessToken()
        val res = call.execute()
        if (res.isSuccessful){

              val newAccessToken = res.body // your new token from response
              //
              response.request
                  .newBuilder()
                  .header("bearerToken", newAccessToken)
                  .build()

        }else{
            return null
        }

        return null
    }

    //
    private val Response.responseCount: Int
        get() = generateSequence(this) { it.priorResponse }.count()

   }
   ```
2. Now you can attach this `Authenticator` to your `OkHttpClient` the same way you do with Interceptors

   ```
   private val client= OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
        .authenticator(MyAuthenticator()) // authenticator we created
        .build()
   ```
3. Finally add this client  to the Retrofit Builder:

   ```
   Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client) // from 2nd step
            .build()
   ```

That's all, Now if 401 error occur, `Authenticator` will be called automatically and token will be refreshed and the pending API will be continued without getting error response.